# Flask routes not working properly with mod_wsgi Apache

Tags: python, apache, flask, wsgi

I'm currently following a Flask Tutorial. When I create the routes they won't work unless I actually create the sub-directories they are calling. If I don't do this I get served the "page not found" page. Other than this issue everything works great. I spent most of yesterday searching for this problem but found nothing that fixes it. This is my first question asked, so feel free to tell me if I have provided too much info or not enough. Thank you.

Directory Structure

```
/public_html
  /deals
     /app
        /__init__.py
       /templates
  /user
     /susan
```

In addition to __init__.py the app directory also contains route.py, models.py, forms.py.

[public_html/deals/passenger_wsgi.py]

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0,"/home/machomes/public_html/deals")

from deals import app as application
```

[public_html/deals/app/__init__.py]

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import SMTPHandler, RotatingFileHandler
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_mail import Mail, Message
from config import Config

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
login = LoginManager(app)
login.login_view = 'login'
mail = Mail(app)

if not app.debug:
    if app.config['MAIL_SERVER']:
        auth = None
        if app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] or app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD']:
            auth = (app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'], app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'])
        secure = None
        if app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS']:
            secure = ()
        mail_handler = SMTPHandler(
            mailhost=(app.config['MAIL_SERVER'], app.config['MAIL_PORT']),
            fromaddr='no-reply@' + app.config['MAIL_SERVER'],
            toaddrs=app.config['ADMINS'], subject='Microblog Failure',
            credentials=auth, secure=secure)
        mail_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
        app.logger.addHandler(mail_handler)

    if not os.path.exists('logs'):
        os.mkdir('logs')
    file_handler = RotatingFileHandler('logs/microblog.log', maxBytes=10240,
                                       backupCount=10)
    file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(
        '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s [in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]'))
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    app.logger.info('Microblog startup')

from app import routes, models, errors
```

[public_html/deals/app/routes.py]

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, request
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, current_user, login_required
from werkzeug.urls import url_parse
from app import app, db
from app.forms import LoginForm, RegistrationForm, EditProfileForm, \
    EmptyForm, PostForm, ResetPasswordRequestForm, ResetPasswordForm
from app.models import User, Post
from app.email import send_password_reset_email


@app.before_request
def before_request():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        current_user.last_seen = datetime.utcnow()
        db.session.commit()


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def index():
    form = PostForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        post = Post(body=form.post.data, author=current_user)
        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your post is now live!')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    posts = current_user.followed_posts().paginate(
        page, app.config['POSTS_PER_PAGE'], False)
    next_url = url_for('index', page=posts.next_num) \
        if posts.has_next else None
    prev_url = url_for('index', page=posts.prev_num) \
        if posts.has_prev else None
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home', form=form,
                           posts=posts.items, next_url=next_url,
                           prev_url=prev_url)

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user is None or not user.check_password(form.password.data):
            flash('Invalid username or password')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        login_user(user, remember=form.remember_me.data)
        next_page = request.args.get('next')
        if not next_page or url_parse(next_page).netloc != '':
            next_page = url_for('index')
        return redirect(next_page)
    return render_template('login.html', title='Sign In', form=form)


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))


@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data)
        user.set_password(form.password.data)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Congratulations, you are now a registered user!')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)
@app.route('/user/<username>')
@login_required
def user(username):
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first_or_404()
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    posts = user.posts.order_by(Post.timestamp.desc()).paginate(
        page, app.config['POSTS_PER_PAGE'], False)
    next_url = url_for('user', username=user.username, page=posts.next_num) \
        if posts.has_next else None
    prev_url = url_for('user', username=user.username, page=posts.prev_num) \
        if posts.has_prev else None
    form = EmptyForm()
    return render_template('user.html', user=user, posts=posts.items,
                           next_url=next_url, prev_url=prev_url, form=form)
```

Comment: Is Apache actually calling your application at all? If you remove Apache from the mix and just start a test server with `app.run()` or `flask run`, does it work correctly?

Comment: I really have no idea. I will look into it and get back to you once I figure out how to do that. Thanks.